# Trying to use ngrx-store-localstorage in nativescript-angular mobile app causes 'localStorage is not defined'

Tags: angular, nativescript, ngrx, angular2-nativescript, ngrx-store

> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
>
> File: "finle:///data/data/org.nativescript/dist/index.js. line 104,
>   column: 40
>
> StackTrace:  Frame:
>   function:'exports.localStorageSync',file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.MyApp/files/app/tns_modules/ngrx-store-localstorage/dist/index.js',line:104,column:41
>   Frame:
>   finction:",file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.MyApp/files/app/core/store/index.js',line:19,column:69

Is it must to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-localstorage
or Can we use https://github.com/natural-apptitude/ngrx-store-ionic-storage
or ngrx-store-localstorage

Comment: It may be possible to hack Cordova plugins to work with NativeScript, but you are much better using nativescript-localstorage.

Answer (score 2):

NativeScript doesn't have LocalStorage. You have to install a shim.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-localstorage
```

Then at the top of your `app.module.ts` before you initialize ngrx:

```
import 'nativescript-localstorage';
```

This should allow ngrx-store-localstorage to work.

Read the docs at:
https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage

Comment: Now it throws this `JS: ERROR Error: No provider for Store!
JS: ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]
JS: ns-renderer: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR
JS: ns-renderer: No provider for Store!
JS: 
JS: Error
JS:     at injectionError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.MyApp/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1238:86) [angular]`

Comment: Remove `ngrx-store-localstorage` and make sure your app is working without it. NativeScript has limited support for Node & browser APIs so getting packages to work can require a lot of hacking.

Make sure you have @ngrx/store set up as specified in the docs:
https://github.com/ngrx/store

Comment: Well this is the fiirst thing I am adding, so rest works fine . I have moved it to a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105335/no-provider-for-store-error-at-injectionerror

Answer (score 0):

you have to do three steps

1 install the plugin

```
tns plugin add nativescript-localstorage
```

2 import it in app.module.ts

```
import 'nativescript-localstorage';
```

3 use it in the corresponding component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService, IDataItem } from "../core/data.service";
require( "nativescript-localstorage" );
@Component({
....
})

 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 ......
}
```